# Is it possible to run a project from a solution in VS 2017 without it being assigned as the start project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a MVC 5 solution in VS 2017 with 2 projects. Sometimes, when I'm working in one, I need to enter new information in the database using the other one. The only way I know of doing this is to stop debugging, assign the other project as the startup, run it, enter the info and then reverse the process again. Is there a way that I can access the project (which is light, not too complex) without stopping the current assigned startup project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Right click on the project and select `Debug > Start New Instance` from the menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the solution name in the solution explorer, there's an option for Set Startup Projects.  You can then select what you want to start when you run the application.

It's also under the Project menu.

Comment: OP specifically asked how to do this _without_ setting the startup project

Comment: @phuzi He asked how to do it without stopping the debugger, changing to a new startup project, and then starting that project.  My answer allows you to start two projects at the same time with a click of a button.  If the OP needs both open most of the time while debugging, this way is a better answer.  If it's an infrequent need, the accepted answer is the best solution.   Putting the information out there will be helpful to someone.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question OP asked though.